# JavaScript making queue from requests

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a function, that requests data from the server and opens a page. And returns a page index. Called - showpage(). Also i have methods - active() ( returns the currently open page index ), next() and previous()

So the next and previous methods under the hood do the showpage() method.

But the problem is when i execute this type of script:

```
console.log(active());
showpage(9998)
console.log(active());
console.log(next());
console.log(active());
```

It should output me:

0,
9998
9999
9999

But istead it gives me somethig absolutely wrong. I understand that this is related to the server requests, that are finished earlier - are messing up the result.

So i created a simple fiddle, that shows my problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/875828/

Here is a small sample:

```
button.on("click", function(){
    makeRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos", 1);
    makeRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments", 2);
    makeRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", 3);
    makeRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums", 4);
    makeRequest("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", 5);
})

function makeRequest(url, id){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
    })
.done(function( data ) {
    console.log(id);
 });
}
```

So the output should be:

1,
2,
3,
4,
5

**There is no jQuery in the project, here it just added for a quick example**

Is there a way to easily make them stand in queue? Somethink similar to SemaphoreSlim in C#?

Comment: Yes, via [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) or, in jQuery, [Deferred objects](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: @Utkanos but if there is no jQuery?

Comment: Via Promises, like I said. That's native JS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update coded using recursion to maintain the sequence. We fill an array of requests and then we process them one by one until there are no more

```
var reqArr= [];

button.on("click", function(){
  reqArr.push({url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos",v:1});
  reqArr.push({url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments",v:2});
  reqArr.push({url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos",v:3});
  reqArr.push({url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums",v:4});
  reqArr.push({url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",v:5});
  makeRequest();
})

function makeRequest(){
  if(reqArr.length==0) return;//stop recursion
  var obj=reqArr.shift();

  $.ajax({
    url: obj.url,
  })
  .done(function( data ) {
    console.log(obj.v);
    return makeRequest();
  });
}
```

Comment: But if i'm not aware of how many requests there will be? In my case, the onClick script is written by the user. And parsing the script is not the option. Maybe there is a way to handle everything in makeRequest function?

Comment: whenever you get a request just push it to the array